# REACT: UseState is not updating the variable (ant design modal form)

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, modal-dialog, ant-design-pro

I'm using Antdesign for this modal.
I have a modal form shown when user click on delete button, this modal has two radio button group , and confirm should call different functions based on selected value. I use UseState for updating the selectedValue, but seems its not getting updated. also I cant change the pre-selected value to the other option. the handler is getting called however.

```
const Signatures = () => {
     const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState('deleteSignature');
     const handleDeleteOptionsChange = (event) => {
      setSelectedOption(event.target.value);
     }
    const onDeleteClick = (id) => {
    Modal.confirm({
      okText: 'Confirm',
      centered: true,
      title: 'To Delete this documents, press \'Confirm\'',
      content: (
        <Radio.Group onChange={handleDeleteOptionsChange} value={selectedOption}>
          <Radio checked={selectedOption ==='deleteSignature'}  value="deleteSignature">Delete signature request</Radio>
          <Radio checked={selectedOption ==='deleteSignatureAndDocument'}  value="deleteSignatureAndDocument">Delete signature request and document</Radio>
        </Radio.Group>
      ),
      onOk: async () => {
          if (selectedOption==='deleteSignature')
          {//return onDeleteSignature(id);} 
          else {//return onDelete(id);}
        
      },
    });
  };

...
return ();
    };
export default Signatures;
```

handleDeleteOptionsChange is being triggered but no state update and no radio button change on UI side

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you add all the component code? Also what does it display when you `console.log(event.target.value)` ?

Comment: @SuleymanSah the component is very large about 500 lines. return contains lots of child components , none of them is related to this modal form.
also event.target.value shows the correct one I selected. but the state is not getting changed

Comment: @SuleymanSah so means I cant use state?

Comment: useEffect(() => { }, [selectedOption])

have you add this?

Comment: It would be good if you can add the code fragments where you used `selectedOption`.

Comment: @SuleymanSah tried it, nothing changed

Comment: @NaveenNizam I havent add this variable as dependencies if you mean so . but should I use useEffect?

Comment: useEffect(() => { }, [selectedOption])  to use **useEffect** continuously update when you changed the data

Comment: @SaraN you can experiment to add this

Comment: @NaveenNizam  canyou help me plz? what should I update inside useEffect ? I cant update State. correct ? it will be infinite loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `selectedValue` and the radio button group aren't getting updated because you are using the `Modal.confirm` method. This is a static method that creates a modal dialog outside of the React component lifecycle. This means that the modal dialog does not have access to the component's state or props, and does not re-render when they change. So to fix this problem, you need to use `Modal` component instead of `Modal.confirm` method.

For example:

```
const Signatures = () => {
  const [selectedOption, setSelectedOption] = useState("deleteSignature");
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
  const handleDeleteOptionsChange = (event) => {
    setSelectedOption(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleOk = async () => {
    if (selectedOption === "deleteSignature") {
      //return onDeleteSignature(id);
    } else {
      //return onDelete(id);
    }
    setVisible(false);
  };

  const handleCancel = () => {
    setVisible(false);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Modal
        visible={visible}
        okText="Confirm"
        centered
        title="To Delete this documents, press 'Confirm'"
        content={
          <Radio.Group
            onChange={handleDeleteOptionsChange}
            value={selectedOption}
          >
            <Radio
              checked={selectedOption === "deleteSignature"}
              value="deleteSignature"
            >
              Delete signature request
            </Radio>
            <Radio
              checked={selectedOption === "deleteSignatureAndDocument"}
              value="deleteSignatureAndDocument"
            >
              Delete signature request and document
            </Radio>
          </Radio.Group>
        }
        onOk={handleOk}
        onCancel={handleCancel}
      />
    </>
  );
};
```

To learn more, see [Ant Design Documentation - Modal](https://ant.design/components/modal)

Comment: Thanks so much it works . you are right. the modal does not re-render after state change. I just made a very small change on your code , since content didnt work for me